# Can I disable ip-conntrack if I have running iptables?

Tags: linux, iptables

following this thread,
[Increasing ip_conntrack_max safely?](https://serverfault.com/questions/111034/increasing-ip-conntrack-max-safely)
I noticed that I use ftp_conntrack, so I decided to remove ip-conntrack.
However it seems it is used by 2-3 other modules, including xt_state and iptables.
any idea if I can remove it anyway?

Answer (score 2):

No, you can not remove modules which have dependent modules loaded.  You can disable iptables, and remove the other modules that use ip-conntrack.  Basically, you will be severely crippling your firewalling. ip-conntrack is one of the core modules that enable iptables to be a stateful firewall.

ftp_conntrack likely also depends ip-conntrack which handles connection tracking most of your connections.  I would expect it is ip-conntrack that tracks the control channel for your FTP connections.